# Relation between "concept" and "conception" 

Tags: nouns, terminology, suffixes

> **concept**: an abstract idea; a general notion
>
> **conception**: the way in which something is perceived or regarded

These two words are troubling me because it seems that there is a way that *concept* and *conception* can be used near-identically or near-interchangeably and in a way that differ only to the extent of some kind of *inflection*.

I'm not a linguist, but I think *inflection*, though very general, might be the grammatical idea most likely to address this problem.  Is there a more specific way of stating the relation between these two usages?

Comment: I doubt there's a recognised term in linguistics for the relationship, but sticking with the metaphor I'd say they are *cousins*. As both answers have made clear, *concept* is not the direct "parent" of *conception* - you have to go back to Latin to find their common ancestor.

Comment: "Conception" refers to the *activity* of creating a concept.

Comment: "Concept" is the baby.  "Conception" is how you make babies.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, *concept* is used when referring to an objective idea/entity (as in *the concept of eleven dimensions is hard to grasp*), while *conception* refers to a certain person's subjective idea of something (as in *his conceptions about English seem a little misguided*).  The difference, then, on at least one level, is **objectivity**.

*[Inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection)* refers to the modification of a word to express different grammatical categories (e.g. *hitting* is an inflected form of *hit*).  This does not apply here.  The only difference between the two nouns *concept* and *conception* is in meaning and usage.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to know the relation as much as the difference.  S/he thought *inflection* might fit, and inflection is a difference, not a relation.  Another giveaway is this quote: *...in a way that **differs** only to the extent of some kind of* inflection.  Though the title and the last line say *relation*, I think the OP already knows the relation - the words are both nouns and both mean *idea*.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't take the credit for that creativity :)  Someone here at ELU used it once.

Comment: FWIW, I found that [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_pronoun#.27.28S.29he.27) also includes s/he as a gender-neutral pronoun substitute.

Comment: +1 Also, you may have seen me use s/he. I'm a big proponent.

Answer (score 2):

*Concept* is derived from Latin *conceptum*, the past participle of *concipio*, and meant ‘that which is conceived’ (but not sexually). *Conception* is also ultimately from the same Latin verb, but comes to us via the noun *conceptio*, of which one meaning was 'the act of becoming pregnant'. That is the meaning it had when it first appeared in English in the early fourteenth century, but it soon started to be used figuratively for ‘the action or faculty of conceiving in the mind, or of forming an idea or notion of anything; apprehension, imagination.’

The relation between the two words is thus to be sought in Latin rather than English. It appears not to be the case, for instance, that *conception* is formed from *concept* by the addition of the suffix *–ion*.

Comment: All that said, how is the Latin etymology relevant to the modern differences/relationships between the words?  To be complete, this answer should show in what way this history affects the current meanings.  The question was on the level of modern grammar/linguistics, not etymology; therefore, unless the etymology helps explain the differences, it is not pertinent.

Comment: It was a roundabout way of knocking on the head the OP's suggestion that there might be an inflectional relationship between the two words in English. There isn't. In spite of their common origin, they are to be treated as two different words that happen to be similarly spelt. I thought it important to establish that point.

Comment: Agreed that *inflection* played no real part in how we come to have these two closely-related words. The route to our modern usage of *conception* is figurative extension from the *conceive* sense. The reason we did this is presumably because we have need of such a word in our conversations and writing. The answer looks correct and comprehensive enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

A concept is an idea of a category or kind that has been generalized from particular instances. Thus, the concept of "cat" arises from the many cats we see. Concept also refers to a widely held idea of what something is or should be: The concept of government of many small nations has been influenced by the legislative and judicial institutions of Britain. The meaning of conception is much like this second sense of concept, but differs in that the idea of what a thing is or should be is here held by an individual or small group and is often coloured by imagination and feeling: A child’s conception of the universe is formed by his limited experience and his own fancies.

Answer (score 0):

While not a technical linguistic term, the phrase ***shades of meaning*** comes to mind to describe the relationship.

I think that the words being somewhat related in form and etymology (and I think @Barrie's answer is very interesting as to how such closely related words acquired their different shades of meaning) is causing some confusion here. I am not sure if the OP means to ask about words that are almost interchangeable AND seem closely related. I chose to answer the first part.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question of what is the linguistic term for the difference between concept and conception:

Yes, linguistics does have a term for such a thing, in fact, it's one of a handful of major fields of study- morphology. Simply put, it's the study of distinct units of meaning smaller than a word. That extra bit of -ion encodes a subtle difference in meaning, which is a general WAY of thinking about something, versus the specific instantiation of that idea.

Inflection doesn't encode changes in meaning per say, but specific types of information which relate words in a sentence in agreement relations, such as person and number. E.g. the subject is singular and 3rd person and this agrees with the verb in 'they cook dinner,' but 'they cooks dinner' is bad. Concept and conception are both nouns and there is no agreement relation, just a relation in meaning.

Inflection is a type of morphology, but it's much more specific. The -ti on here would be considered derivational mirohology. This type of morphology may also change a words category, e.g. help (noun) and help-ing (verb).

Answer (score 0):

How does a batsman get a run in cricket? He initiates the process by leaving the crease and running towards the other crease. When he reaches the other crease successfully, it is deemed that he has secured a 'run'. ' Conception ' refers to the process, like running. 'Concept' is like  the 'run'. When a man is engaged in walking, he may  cover some distance at a given time, say five kilo meters. After an hour, he might have crossed ten kilometers if he continues walking. Now, the process remains the same but the result changes through time. Thus,
 the process of conception is same.But the concept of even the same individual may undergo changes, though his process of conceiving might not have changed. Some times, even the way one conceives, i.e, his conception,  his tools and ways of thinking may also change.

Comment: Not really.  In your example, conception would be the act of starting to run from the crease.  Concept is the entity known in cricket as a *run*.